# javascript for multiple textboxes

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have 10 textboxes for name qty1-10, price1-10 and total1-10 for each of these. All i'm doing is adding the values of qty1+price1 = total1, qty2+price2=total2 etc..

This is my current code -

```
function Add()
  {
    var qty1 = document.getElementById('qty1').value; 
    var u_price1 = document.getElementById('price1').value; 
    if (qty1 == "") {
        if (u_price1 == "") {
            document.form1.total1.value = "null";
            return;
            }
        document.form1.total1.value = "null";
        return;
        }
    else
    {
       document.form1.total1.value = Number(qty1) + Number(u_price1);
    }    
  }
```

Now I want to write a for loop that will use the same code but change names of qty1 to qty2 and so on.

Comment: thanks, upto 55% now. will do more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign class to those textboxes and then do

`var arr = document.getElementByClassName('classname')`

You will get array of textbox on which you can apply for loop and then execute your code in the loop.

(I'm not writing the code because its basics of Javascript which you should do on your own)

Answer (score 0):

Pass in the ID of the grouping you want as a parameter. Then you can call the function in a loop.

```
function Add(ID) {
    var qty1 = document.getElementById('qty'+ID).value; 
    var u_price1 = document.getElementById('price'+ID).value; 
    ...
}
```

Comment: but I have only 1 submit button. So can you tell me how I can do this at textbox level?

Comment: Add more buttons that are not submit buttons that call your JS function.